# Sending email with appgyver, steroids

Tags: android, iphone

I have installed the emailcomposer plugin for appgyver,steroids.

How do I actually use it to send a email from a form?
I dont really know how to implement the plugin in my app, anyone that used it care to share some info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are usage instructions in the plugin's [readme](https://github.com/AppGyver/email-composer), so just call

```
window.plugins.emailComposer.showEmailComposerWithCallback(callback,subject,body,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,isHtml,attachments,attachmentsData);
```

with the data from your form. This should open up a new screen where the email can be sent.